# What does it mean if the TTY field is a question mark?

Tags: tty, ps

What does it mean when `ps` lists a process's TTY as `?` instead of a tty device name/number?

For example:

```
piotr@thinkpad:~$ ps -A | head -2 
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:04 systemd
```

The TTY is represented by **?** and for example bash TTY is **0**

Answer (score 0):

It has disassociated itself from the controlling `pty`.

See:

- [Why MUST detach from tty when writing a linux daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777602/why-must-detach-from-tty-when-writing-a-linux-daemon)